# simple for-(function/operation)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple for-operation in Python.

I have one variable, where I have to give an input, which is called weight_lbs. So the input and outcome there is a string. Then I am easily converting the weight of weight_lbs into weight_kg.

I want the outcome, `"That´s a lot"` if the weight in kg is bigger than `200`
and `print("You´re weight in kg is " + weight_kg "!")` else

```
weight_lbs = input("weight (lbs): ")

weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45

for i in int(weight_kg):
    if i > 200:
        print("That´s a lot")
    else:
       print("You´re weight in kg is " + weight_kg "!")
```

Comment: Side note: `'` is the apostrophe, not `´`. And if it belongs to you, it's "your", not "you're".

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistakes. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with check out if it works for you

```
weight_lbs = input("weight (lbs): ")

weight_kg = int(weight_lbs) * 0.45

if int(weight_lbs) > 200:
    print("That's a lot")
else:
    print("Your weight in kg is " + str(weight_kg) + "!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` is a statement you use for *looping*, which means doing something repeatedly. Say if you have a list of numbers, you could use `for` to do something for each number in turn.

You have a single weight. You don't need to loop over anything, so you don't need `for`.